# Which predictive model is best fit here?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, binary-data, artificial-intelligence

I have two predictor variable both numeric with right skew. My outcome variable is binary as positive and negative. Sample size id 157 and positive cases are only 10. That's just 6.37%. I know there is a class imbalance here. and with this sample size which predictive model is best feasible.
I have worked on logistics, glms and a couple of times mixed models. But this predictive modeling is pretty new to me.

Any suggestions or any documentation that explains similar condition is appreciated.

Thank you community for your help

Comment: The prevalence of your outcome is too small to justify most predictive models.  Logistic regressions (flawed, but often used) 1-in-10 EPV rule would prevent you from fitting a glm to this data.  I imagine requirements for any other ML models would be even more stringent.  Can you get more data?

Comment: Class imbalance won’t be such an issue, but the sheer lack of many observations of the one class is likely to be problematic. In other words, if you had $15700$ total observations and $10000$ of that one class, I would not be concerned.

Comment: @demetri Thank you for your reply. With this dataset I tried simple logistic model but I am not sure of the goodness of fit. I read the documentation on firth bias correction but data doesn’t show a separation. 

I am very new to ML concepts and I was wondering if there were any model which accounts for a similar situation. But Like Dave said the sample size is too low to even fit an algorithm. 

I synthesized data using ROSE package and developed a Random Forest model with accuracy at 0.77 sensitive at .6 and specificity at .8 My AUC was .76 Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @dave thanks for the reply. I am literally stuck at this right now. The only test I could run to see is Man Whitney U